# html5 apps automated testing

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, html, automated-tests, backbone.js

Are where any good frameworks for automated testing HTML5 apps?

I'm now writing an app which should work offline in iOS Safari and it would be awesome if there were some automated testing tools. I have no idea how to test `cache.manifest` properly, for example.

I'm using Backbone.js, by the way. That would be even better if the tool relies on it or interacts with it in a good way

Answer (score 5):

Answering by listing a link is not always the best way to go, but hey someone did the work before me: http://tinnedfruit.com/2011/03/03/testing-backbone-apps-with-jasmine-sinon.html

Jasmine.js to test
Sinon.js to mock